# xamarin When people click comma (,) on a numeric keyboard nothing happens

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I've inherited a Xamarin (Forms 5.0.0.2587) app with a few number inputs. These inputs are EntryCells with a Keyboard.Numeric.

This application is made for a Danish company and some of their users have started reporting that they can't enter decimal numbers as nothing happens when they press comma.

They forwarded an email from one of those customers with a screenshot of this keyboard

[image: Numeric keyboard with a grey , and a button with . and - as the same button]

And it does look disabled there. The button "Klar" seems to be in Danish interestingly enough. But the comma is disabled. On my own (and another test phone) there is a non-disabled comma but pressing it does nothing. I can change languages on the test phone and have period be the button that does nothing and the comma button will enter a comma. But as far as I know the customers do have their phones in Danish.

There are these in App()

```cs
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
```

Which seems like they should do something, but they don't? I don't have that much Xamarin and Android experience in the first place, and I'm not even sure if there is anything I can do about this. It seems not but suggestions would be nice

Comment: "as far as I know the customers do have their phones in Danish" - is that an assumption or do you know this as a fact? Let's avoid chasing ghosts. If the phone is set to English, the period would be correct.

Comment: What is the keyboard input method language?

Comment: @Julian I base that off of the picture I got sent with the problem and with a button in Danish. And what I am being told by my customer